# Configure webflow paths with multiple folder structures

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow

I have my Spring Webflow configured to build its paths in the following manner

```
@Bean
public FlowDefinitionRegistry flowRegistry() {
    return getFlowDefinitionRegistryBuilder(flowBuilderServices())
    .setBasePath("/WEB-INF/views/flows")
    .addFlowLocationPattern("/**/*-flow.xml")
    .build();
}
```

Which works great, I have a folder structure like this:

```
-views
    --flows
        ---myFlowA
               a-flow.xml
        ---myFlowB
               b-flow.xml
        ---myFlowC
               c-flow.xml
```

So navigating to *root*/myFlowA loads the flow described by a.xml and so on.

However, we'd like to be able to have a route structure that also supports paths like  ***root*/otherPath/myFlowD**.

So I guess our folder structure would look like:

```
-views
    --flows
        ---myFlowA
               a-flow.xml
        ---myFlowB
               b-flow.xml
        ---myFlowC
               c-flow.xml
        ---otherPath
            ----myFlowD
               d-flow.xml
            ----myFlowE
               e-flow.xml
```

How do I support that in my flow configuration?

Comment: your current configuration should work

Comment: Hmmm, well I'm getting 404s when I try and access root/otherPath/myFlowD with this setup.

Comment: my configuration uses <webflow:flow-location-pattern value="/WEB-INF/flows/**/*-flow.xml" /> and it works fine

Comment: from your configuration your xml files should end with -flow.xml but they don't... maybe you should use "**/\*.xml" instead of "**/\*-flow.xml"

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the -flow.xml part in my example above. In my actual program they do have that. So, you're saying you have  value="/WEB-INF/flows/**/*-flow.xml" as your pattern and are actually able to access flows with other levels of "subdirectories"? That's odd that I get 404s then.

Comment: I don't use basePath though, so it's a bit different.

Comment: what is your servlet mapping?

Comment: could you add your flowExecutor and flowRegistry?